# convert local variable to global in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can I make **data_subset**(*pc0.on("brush", function(data_subset)*) as global variable?
 I would like to use the filtered data after brushing event in some other code outside this function.
This is my first project with d3.js(or JavaScript) so I'm sorry if the question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Sample code:

```
d3.csv('data/cars.csv', function(data) {


    pc0 = d3.parcoords()("#example0")
      .data(data)
        .bundlingStrength(0) // set bundling strength
        .smoothness(0)
        .bundleDimension("cylinders")
        .showControlPoints(false)
        .hideAxis(["name"])
        .render()
        .brushMode("1D-axes")
        .reorderable()
        .interactive();

     // create data table, row hover highlighting
        var grid0 = d3.divgrid();

        d3.select("#grid0")
           .datum(data.slice(0,5))
           .call(grid0)
           .selectAll(".row")
           .on({
             "mouseover": function(d0) { pc0.highlight([d0]) },
             "mouseout": pc0.unhighlight
        });

          // update data table on brush event
        pc0.on("brush", function(data_subset) {
           d3.select("#grid")
          .datum(data_subset.slice(0,5))
          .call(grid0)
          .selectAll(".row")
          .on({
            "mouseover": function(data_subset) { pc0.highlight([data_subset]) },
            "mouseout": pc0.unhighlight
          });          

      });
```

Comment: You can make anything global by assigning it to the `window` object. That said, I'm sure you're aware that global state is evil so use it sparingly!

Answer (score 2):

Iamjpg gave you the correct answer regarding your specific question. However, in case you don't know, if you want to turn all your data global (or one scope above the level of the CSV function), it's very simple:

```
var globalData;  

d3.csv('data/cars.csv', function(data) {  

  globalData = data;  

  //the rest of your code.  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Calvin Belden's comment says you can attach anything to the `window` object but isn't recommended.

One thing you can do is the following (excuse pseudo code):

```
// Object declaration outside of d3 call which you can store data in.
var dict = {}

d3.csv('data/cars.csv', function(data) {
  var something = data.something_else;
  dict.something = something;
}

var some_other_function = function() {
  var foo = dict.something;
}
```

Comment: Variable **data_subset** that I'm trying to extract is an input for a function inside function(you can see it in the last chunk of script in my sample code).

Comment: Declaring object outside this inner function, does not help.
console.log() outputs undefined.

Comment: If that's the case, why not declare your other function first and then pass whatever data you want from your mouseover callback function (`data_subset` I'm guessing) to that declared function outside of D3?

Comment: I'm not sure this approach would help me. What I want to do is to have two parallel-coordinate charts with a brush function(stats of basketball games to be precise).After using brush on both of them: lets say filter first chart to include teams with high rebounds , second with low assist...
My goal is to show some win/lose ratio of teams from chart1 vs chart2.

Comment: So that function should use input from two different onclick functions